# C++ coloring console output

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I colorate a specific item from an array of characters ?  So I have someting like : 
char a[50] where a[4] = "c". How can I colorate that character ? I only know how to colorate all characters using something like this :

```
HANDLE hConsole;
hConsole = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute
(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
```

Comment: I am guessing which is why this is a comment, but I suspect you need to change the colour for either individual or possibly ranges of chars - so you'll need to have a process inbetween the console and the process outputting the text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would have to print one character at a time, and switch between your color1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [WriteConsoleOutput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but you'll need to manage positioning of these characters explicitly as it doesn't use the cursor.